# How do I close serial connection when I interrupt code

Tags: python, pyserial

I have the following Python code which is just reading from an Arduino, and writing to a file:

```
import serial
from datetime import datetime
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0)

text_file = open("voltages.txt", 'w') 

while 1:
    x=ser.readline()
    print(str(datetime.now()), x) 
    data = [str(datetime.now()),x]
    text_file.write("{}\n".format(data))
    text_file.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Whenever I interrupt the script, I always have to type `ser.close()` in the console, otherwise I cannot start the script again (in the same console).

How can I close the serial communication automatically whenever I interrupt the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [try/finally](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) block to insure close is called:

```
try:
    while 1:
        x = ser.readline()
        ....
finally:
    ser.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `with` statement.

```
import serial
from datetime import datetime
import time

with serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0) as ser, open("voltages.txt", 'w') as text_file:
    while True:
        x=ser.readline()
        print(str(datetime.now()), x) 
        data = [str(datetime.now()),x]
        text_file.write("{}\n".format(data))
        text_file.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```

The `with` statement will automatically close `ser` and `text_file` when execution leaves the `with` statement. This can be an exception in your case. The `with` statement has been introduced by PEP 343 to remove `try/finaly` statements by using context managers.